# The errors report by IntelliJ IDEA I can not find

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

In the snapshot you can see, there is 20 errors in the BaseDaoImpl, But I can not find where it is in the `BaseDaoImpl.java`.

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: That screenshot doesn't really show anything, except that you are looking at the wrong lines (the red section is higher than where you have scrolled)

Comment: @224boy have you use cursor point at the rea place at the slide block ?

Comment: @aircraft now I did, see my edit

Comment: `@Description`? `@date`? These are supposed to be valid JavaDoc tags? And has UnholySheep said, look where your scollbar is and where the red lines are.

Comment: tried rebuilding the project? are you using ant, maven or gradle?

Comment: @224boy, it shows, the `Illegal character`, if is those lines is copied from other place?

Comment: @aircraft yes, how to solve it?

Comment: `U+2028` should be the unicode for *Line Separator*, so you most likely have an invalid invisible character in all those lines (as aircraft suggested this most likely happened when you copy pasted those lines from somewhere else)

Comment: If your code have Illegal character, you can cut them out, then use Notepad++, copy the code to it, and execute `format` -> convert to `UTF-8 non BOM`.